# Could not load file or assembly 'MySqlBackup, Version=2.0.9.2

Tags: vb.net

Consider:

```
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ServerString)
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
cmd.Connection = conn
conn.Open()
Dim mb As MySqlBackup = New MySqlBackup(cmd)
mb.ExportToFile("C:\backup.sql")
conn.Close()
```

I keep getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MySqlBackup, Version=2.0.9.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: is *your* app strongly named?

Comment: You may have a different/incorrect version of MySqlBackup.dll installed in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache).

Comment: it actually sounds like a version mismatch between MySqlBackUp and MySql which it requires.  The current version on NuGet is 2.0.9.4 which requires MySql 6.9.8

Comment: I've tried MySql 6.9.8 and MySql 6.9.9 connector, same error. I've downloaded the current version of  MySqlBackup.dll which is 2.0.9.4 using NuGet package manager, but in the properties it says, the version is 2.0.9.2

Comment: It won't work with 6.9.9 anyway. It's apparently tied to 6.9.8 since I got one of those "Could not load file or assembly" for MySQL.Data v6.9.8 when I tried to test your code since I have 6.9.9 loaded (and Nuget also loaded it as well) though it was manifest didn't match rather than strongly named assembly req.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem, by uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio. Then I installed MySqlBackup.NET (using NuGet package manager) version 2.0.9.3, which automatically installed *MySql.Data* version 6.9.9. It works perfectly. I'm not saying that's the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For now, one only can assume,

1. See the version actually referenced and used in the application.
2. Look in the *.vbproj* file for *System.Windows.Forms*,

   If it exists, try removing this.
3. Build your solution on 32-bit and 64-bit one at a time and see if it works on either of them

Moreover, I assume number 1 and 3 can be, but I cannot be sure. Try it.